Cannot run sagemaker pyspark locally on notebook instance, conda_python3 kernel missing
I am attempting to use pyspark on sagemaker notebooks as described here:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-spark/tree/master/sagemaker-pyspark-sdk#local-spark-on-sagemaker-notebook-instances
The page reads:
Local Spark on SageMaker Notebook Instances
Create a notebook using the conda_python2 or conda_python3 Kernels. Then you can initialize a spark context the same way it is described in the QuickStart section:
I attempted to use either of the two kernels using the Data Science 3.0 image as well as others. None had the conda_python2 or conda_python3 Kernels described, and using the Python 3 Kernel gave a Java Home not found error, as I expected since I'm not connected to an EMR cluster

The link recommends using SageMaker Notebook Instances. Based on your comment on using Data Science image, I assume you're using Studio Notebooks.
Once you create a notebook instance, you will be able to see the conda_python2 or conda_python3 kernels. Studio Notebooks (Classic) have images like Data Science, SparkMagic, Tensorflow etc. and they usually just have a Python kernel.
